# TFS Override the latest change

Tags: tfs

I have a file that was checked in and is part of a C# project.  However, this file is incorrect and it overwrote the previous change which was correct. I need the latest change of this file to revert back to the previous changeset, and I need the previous changeset to be the latest change.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can roll back to the previous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) changeset. [This option is only available from the commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx).

> tf rollback /toversion:VersionSpec ItemSpec [/recursive] [/lock:none|checkin|checkout] [/version:versionspec] [/keepmergehistory] [/login:username,[password]] [/noprompt]

[Alternatively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), use Get Specific Version (check all the boxes to override the files) to get the version of the file you want, check the file out and check it back in again. When prompted to resolve merge conflicts, select use local version. This will create a new version on top of the incorrectly checked-in one.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the TFS Power Tool, you can roll back the changeset. With the Power Tool installed, you can do this in the GUI. Select the changeset in a history list, and right click and select **Rollback entire changeset**.

Here's a nice article:
http://www.edsquared.com/2010/02/02/Rollback+Or+Undo+A+Changeset+In+TFS+2010+Version+Control.aspx

From this article:
[image]

You find the TFS Power Tool here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f